# Collection view not obeying constraints in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, ios-autolayout

I have a collection view that has its edges constrained to the safe area. However, the collection view fully covers the entire screen. Now if I change the contstraints remove the top constrain and change it to a fixed height constraint, the collection view STILL ignores it and fills the whole screen. When i remove all constraints, the collection view does not fill the whole screen. This error only affects the top constraint, all other constraints work fine.

UPDATE:
when I comment out some lines in the headerView supplementary view delegate function, it works again:

```
  func pressedColour(colour: UIColor){

        let origImage = self.imageView?.image
        let tintedImage = origImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.setImage(tintedImage, for: .highlighted)
        //self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.tintColor = colour
    }
```

The lines I comment out call that function. The autolayout error is

```
2018-09-13 23:38:16.556318+0100 DoppelChat[59765:15398941] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028a780 UICollectionView:0x7fac548e6600.top == UILayoutGuide:0x60c0001bea00'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60c0004892e0 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' UIView:0x7fac59a7e150.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':_UIParallaxDimmingView:0x7fac59a7eb90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00048b4a0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(64)-[UILayoutGuide:0x60c0001bea00'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fac59a7e150 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028a780 UICollectionView:0x7fac548e6600.top == UILayoutGuide:0x60c0001bea00'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I have narrowed it down to this line causing the issue:

```
let origImage = self.imageView?.image
```

Comment: no, just a regular view controller

Comment: also there is nothing to show with the constraints, it is just regular align to top

Comment: ok, I added the constraints

Answer (score 0):

ok, well I solved it, if it means anything to you, I used this function for button pressed colour instead:

```
func pressedColour(colour: UIColor, uiImage: UIImage?,  alphaMultiplier: CGFloat){
        let origImage = uiImage
        let tintedImage = origImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.setImage(tintedImage, for: .highlighted)
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        colour.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
        self.tintColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha * alphaMultiplier)
    }
```

and the uiImage argument i passed in was the image literal not the button.imageview.image